# Adding duplicate Actor to stage wont shop up

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have written a basic Inventory system and when I add an Item it gets added properly which is good, but when I go to remove the items from the inventory, it checks if its stackable, and if its amount is greater then 1, so when i drop the items, i see the amount going down by 1, but the item does not get placed at the player, it only gets places once the amount is 1 and i drop again, it will remove from inventory and drop at the players location.

```
public void removeItem(int index) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(slots[index])) {
            slots[index].setX(player.getX());
            slots[index].setY(player.getY());

            if (slots[index].isStackable() && slots[index].getAmount() > 1) {
                slots[index].setAmount(slots[index].getAmount() - 1);
                Item dropItem = slots[index];

                dropItem.setAmount(1);
                StageManager.addActor(dropItem);
            } else {
                StageManager.addActor(slots[index]);
                slots[index] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

It appears only the else statement will drop the item at the player

```
} else {
    StageManager.addActor(slots[index]);
    slots[index] = null;
}
```

I am not sure why it does not -1 the amount like it does, but why it does not drop the dropItem at the player when it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

So i just had to create a new item.

```
public void removeItem(int index) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(slots[index])) {
            slots[index].setX(player.getX());
            slots[index].setY(player.getY());

            if (slots[index].isStackable() && slots[index].getAmount() > 1) {
                slots[index].setAmount(slots[index].getAmount() - 1);

                Item dropItem = new Item(slots[index].getId(), slots[index].getEntityType(), slots[index].getName(), (int)player.getX(), (int)player.getY(),
                        slots[index].getImage(), slots[index].getItemType(), slots[index].getSlotType(), slots[index].getLevel(), slots[index].getRarity(),
                        slots[index].getWeight(), 1, slots[index].getDescription(), slots[index].getAttributes(), slots[index].getShapeRenderer(), slots[index].isStackable());

                StageManager.addActor(dropItem);
            } else {
                StageManager.addActor(slots[index]);
                slots[index] = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For further insight to this, I believe you can't add the same `Actor` more than once to the same `Stage`. Instead the latter `.addActor()` updates the single actor.